# Robotux's macro recorder, capture only mouse and not keyboard key not captured

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I have installed the [robotux](https://abatzill.de/cms/index.php/Robotux) as macro recorder for auto recording the macros in my Ubuntu 18.04 and when i run the captured macros , it works fine but don't recorded the keys pressed during the records!

my language is Persian and English like this:

[image]

in the macro it have captured mouse only like this:

[image]

my Ubuntu version is :

```
so@so-notebook:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Thanks.